# laravel homestead -cant get custom domain to work

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

I have successfully installed Vagrant and Homestead on my machine. I can ssH into the vagrant box and when I rul `ls -n` i can see my projects. However, when I run `serve homestead.app /home/vagrant/Code/cstoss'. I see nothing.

I was able to access the site through http://127.0.0.1, but after trying to figure some stuff out on my own only broke the server (now I'm seeing a 403 Forbidden error).

Here is my Homestead.yaml file

```
    ---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/code/Laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

and my /etc/hosts

```
    #
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
192.168.10.10   homestead.app
```

Comment: You are not supposed to `serve`, you should just `vagrant up`.

Comment: @user2094178 says who? Serving is the easiest way to switch between projects